# Error Executing an update/delete query in Spring 4 MVC+Hibernate 4+MySQL+Maven

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have an application (Spring 4 MVC+Hibernate 4+MySQL+Maven integration example using annotations) , integrating Spring with Hibernate using annotation based configuration but I have an error updating an object !

Here my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    DeviceService deviceService;

    @Autowired
    DeviceEventService deviceEventService;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationService applicationService;

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;




    /*
     * This method will list all existing devices.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/list" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listDevices(ModelMap model) {


        Device device = new Device("E506");
        DeviceEvent deviceEvent = new DeviceEvent(device);
        deviceEvent.setCoordinates(deviceEvent.new Coordinates(Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE));
        deviceEvent.setMessage("message");
        deviceEvent.setReceived(new Date().getTime());

        deviceEventService.save(deviceEvent);       

        model.addAttribute("devices", deviceService.findAll());
        return "alldevices";
    }
```

service:

```
@Service("deviceEventService")
@Transactional
public class DeviceEventServiceImpl implements DeviceEventService {

    @Autowired
    private DeviceEventDao dao;


    public void save(DeviceEvent deviceEvent) {
        dao.save(deviceEvent);      
    }

}
```

the dao:

```
@Repository("deviceEventDao")
public class DeviceEventDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, DeviceEvent> implements DeviceEventDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

    public void save(DeviceEvent deviceEvent) {

        manager.createNamedQuery("insertDeviveEvent", DeviceEvent.class)
                .setParameter(1, deviceEvent.getDevice().getKey())
                .setParameter(2, deviceEvent.getCoordinates().getLat())
                .setParameter(3, deviceEvent.getCoordinates().getLng()).setParameter(4, deviceEvent.getMessage())
                .setParameter(5, deviceEvent.getReceived()).executeUpdate();

    }
}
```

Here the configuration file:

```
@Configuration

@EnableTransactionManagement

@ComponentScan({ "fr.telecom.devices.configuration" })

@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })

public class HibernateConfiguration {



    @Autowired

    private Environment environment;



    @Bean

    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

       LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

       em.setDataSource(dataSource());

       em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "fr.telecom.devices.model" });



       JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

       em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

       em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());



       return em;

    }



    Properties additionalProperties() {

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");

        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

        return properties;

     }



    @Bean

    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());

        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "fr.telecom.devices.model" });

        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;

     }


    @Bean

    public DataSource dataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));

        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));

        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));

        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));

        return dataSource;

    }



    private Properties hibernateProperties() {

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));

        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));

        return properties;        

    }



@Bean

    @Autowired

    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {

       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();

       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);

       return txManager;

    }

}
```

and here the Error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
causa raíz


javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:71)
    fr.telecom.devices.dao.DeviceEventDaoImpl.save(DeviceEventDaoImpl.java:18)
    fr.telecom.devices.service.DeviceEventServiceImpl.save(DeviceEventServiceImpl.java:19)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy340.save(Unknown Source)
    fr.telecom.devices.controller.AppController.listDevices(AppController.java:58)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Comment: First off all why are you using an insert query and not simply let hibernate do that for you? Just persist the entity, second you are using JPA but are using a plain Hibernate transaction manager that isn't going to work. Use the `JpaTransactionManager` instead.